# How to use data binding in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, code-behind

I want to bind my controls with my view model in WPFand automatically update data controls when my database is updated.
I implemented a view model that has some `List<myClass>` properties and receives data from a data base that will be saved in these properties. Then I bind my controls source to these properties. It's ok, but when I get new data from data base and save it in in these properties, the controls data does not update.
How can I fix it programmatically?

This is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ListOfPerson personList1 = new ListOfPerson();
    ListOfPerson personList2 = new ListOfPerson();
    

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        personList1.People.Add(new Person { PersonName = "test1" });
        personList2.People.Add(new Person { PersonName = "test2" });

        dg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        PropertyPath prop = new PropertyPath("PersonName");
        Binding bind = new Binding();
        bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        bind.Path = prop;
        dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Name", Binding = bind });
        dg.ItemsSource = personList1.People;
    }
    public void Refresh()
    {
        personList1.People = personList2.People;
    }

    private void btn_Refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(string value)
    {
        this.name = value;
    }

    public string PersonName
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

```
public class ListOfPerson : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
    public List<Person> People
    {
        get
        {
            return people;
        }
        set
        {
            people = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: In case you are intending to add elements to a `List<Person>` after it was assigned to the People property of a ListOfPerson, you should use ObservableCollection instead of List.

Comment: Tanks. But I use Observable Collection and it's has this problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign your `ItemsSource` directly, that is **not a binding**.

```
dg.ItemsSource = personList1.People;
```

On `Refresh` however, you replace the `People` collection of `personList1`.

```
personList1.People = personList2.People;
```

The items source still has the reference to the old collection, since you assigned it directly. You could instead add a binding, which would notice that the items source changed through the property changed notification implementation in `ListOfPerson` for the `People` property. This should work:

```
Binding itemsSourceBinding = new Binding
{
    Source = personList1,
    Path = new PropertyPath("People")
};
BindingOperations.SetBinding(dg, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, itemsSourceBinding);
```

This is only one option to handle this scenario. Another option is to use just a **single** [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0) that you `Clear` and fill again or modify in between (if your replace it with a **new instance** like the list in your code, you run into the same issue as above). It implements the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=net-5.0) interface and notifies changes, like adding, removing or inserting items automatically, which updates the UI in turn.

Comment: `PropertyPath("personList1.People")` will only work when personList1 is a public property. You might use it as Source instead, with `PropertyPath("People")`.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, your are right, I overlooked that the person lists are actually fields.

Comment: `Source = personList1.People` would not get triggered by PropertyChanged.

Comment: @thatguy Tanks. So I need to create new binding for each controls in application that uses Joint Property? I check that if after `personList1.People = personList2.People;` I use `dg.ItemsSource = personList1.People;`, it's will be ok. But I want soloution that doesn't need to implement for every controls. I use INotifyCollectionChanged, but it's not working good.

Comment: @MaryamHeydari Without a binding, the property update will not work. Of course, reassigning the `ItemsSource` in this case works, because you assign a _different instance_ of a list.